# For all triangle prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{bc}{a^4+2b^2c^2}\leq\frac{3}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be sides-lengths of a triangle. Prove that:
$$\frac{bc}{a^4+2b^2c^2}+\frac{ca}{b^4+2c^2a^2}+\frac{ab}{c^4+2a^2b^2}\leq\frac{3}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$ 
I tried C-S, SOS, uvw and more, but without success.

BW with computer kills it of course, but I look for a human proof.

Thank you!

Comment: Michael, what is "BW?"

Comment: @Dr. MV See here: https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h522084